# view current table order

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin there is an option to alter the current table order....how can I know what the current order is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There is no such thing.

To be precise: in MyISAM engine, current order is whatever the order was when the last `ALTER TABLE ORDER BY` was performed, modified by all the deletions and insertions since.

InnoDB just sorts the tables as it wishes.